# Inverse transform sampling implementation using a random generator and a list of numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have to implement a function in a programming language (Scheme) that do the following.

Given a list of pairs, element and a number, it will return the element. The number on each pair is the probability to return the element in its pair. E.g., if I have the following list **(a 1), (b 2), (c 3)**, and if I run that function 6,000 times, I will get the following results:

```
a -  998 times
b - 2003 times
c - 2999 times
```

The probability to get **a** is **1/6**, **b** is **2/6** and **c** is **3/6**.

The programming language has a function, named **random**, that returns real numbers between 0 and 1. To implement this function I have to use that random function and the Inverse transform sampling, but I don't know how.

By the way, the list of pairs can change on each call to that function.

What do I have to do to implement that function using Inverse transform sampling?

Comment: In your example :set x=random; if random<1/6 return a; if 1/6+2/6>random >1/6 return c; else return c

Comment: if 1/6+2/6>random >1/6 return b (not c)